# .locale & & .updateConfiguration() are deprecated

Tags: java, android, localization, locale, deprecated

I tried to change the app language with Menu resources like this:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.eng:
                String languageToLoad = "en";

                Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
                Locale.setDefault(locale);

                Configuration config = new Configuration();
                config.locale = locale; // deprecated!!

                getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                        getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());  // deprecated!!

                this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                break;

            case R.id.de:
                languageToLoad = "de";

                locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
                Locale.setDefault(locale);

                config = new Configuration();
                config.locale = locale;  // deprecated!!

                getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                        getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());  // deprecated!!

                this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Also `compileSdkVersion 25`, `minSdkVersion 16`, `targetSdkVersion 25`
I know the replacement is to use `createConfigurationContext`, but I don't know how to use it.
I tried this, But it didn't work:

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.eng:
                String languageToLoad = "en";

                Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
                Locale.setDefault(locale);

                Configuration overrideConfiguration = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
                overrideConfiguration.setLocale(locale);
                Context context  = createConfigurationContext(overrideConfiguration);
                Resources resources = context.getResources();

                this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                break;
```

How should I apply this new method to my code!?

Comment: check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46939076/2305119