# Simple way to change locale in android API 25

Tags: android, localization, android-7.1-nougat

I have already checked the solutions with the wrapper and the other suggestions but it seems too much work for something so simple in the previous api.
Actually a way to replace updateConfiguration which was deprecated in api 25 would resolve the issue

[Android N change language programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39705739/android-n-change-language-programatically/40849142#40849142)

[Android context.getResources.updateConfiguration() deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40221711/android-context-getresources-updateconfiguration-deprecated)

[Android context.getResources.updateConfiguration() deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40221711/android-context-getresources-updateconfiguration-deprecated/40291570#40291570)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found with no `updateConfiguration()` is from this answer :
[Android N change language programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39705739/android-n-change-language-programatically/40849142#40849142)

At least for now using context wrapper is the simplest solution.