# Set locale during app startup

Tags: android

I've managed to change the app locale during launch when the user selects a language in a dialog by updating the configuration and relaunching the app.

```
private void changeAppLanguage(String languageCode) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageCode);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Resources resources = mContext.getResources();
    Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();

    // minSdkVersion: 16
    configuration.locale = locale;
    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
}

private void restartActivity() {
    finish();
    Intent iMainActivity = getIntent();
    startActivity(iMainActivity);
}
```

However, on a cold app launch I'm not able to set up the Locale **before** the MainActivity launches: it just won't load the correct string resources and I can't / don't want to restart the activity on the first launch! 
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong since I've already tried calling `changeAppLanguage()` in different orders in `onCreate()`.

```
@Override        
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    changeAppLanguage(getLanguageCode());

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    variousSetups();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this for an activity, then you can call your `changeAppLanguage(getLanguageCode())` in activity's overriden `attachBaseContext(Context)`.

In general, doing this only in activity isn't enough to fully apply locale. What I eventually implemented is based on solutions from these two posts:

- https://gunhansancar.com/change-language-programmatically-in-android/
- https://proandroiddev.com/change-language-programmatically-at-runtime-on-android-5e6bc15c758

I put the calls to `LocalHelper.onAttach(context)`/`LocaleManager.setLocale(context)`/`whatever you call it` in this places:

1. Activity's `attachBaseContext()`

   ```
   @Override
   protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
       super.attachBaseContext(LocaleUtil.setLocale(base));
   }
   ```
2. Application's `attachBaseContext()` (the same as for activities)

   ```
   @Override
   protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
       super.attachBaseContext(LocaleUtil.setLocale(base));
   }
   ```
3. Application's `onConfigurationChanged()`

   ```
   @Override
   public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
       super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
       LocaleUtil.setLocale(this);
   }
   ```
4. In my `SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` implementation

   ```
   @Override
   public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
       if (LocaleUtil.SELECTED_LANGUAGE.equals(key)) {
           context = LocaleUtil.setLocale(context);
           ...
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding it to the Application OnCreate() method.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the same problem and after spending hours on StackOverflow and GitHub, I found a nice working solution.

1. Create a class LocaleHelper

   ```
    public class LocaleHelper {

        private static final String SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "Locale.Helper.Selected.Language";

        public static Context onAttach(Context context) {
            String lang = getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
            return setLocale(context, lang);
        }

        public static Context onAttach(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
            String lang = getPersistedData(context, defaultLanguage);
            return setLocale(context, lang);
        }

        public static String getLanguage(Context context) {
            return getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
        }

        public static Context setLocale(Context context, String language) {
            persist(context, language);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                return updateResources(context, language);
            }

            return updateResourcesLegacy(context, language);
        }

        private static String getPersistedData(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            return preferences.getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, defaultLanguage);
        }

        private static void persist(Context context, String language) {
            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

            editor.putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, language);
            editor.apply();
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
            Locale locale = new Locale(language);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);

            Resources resources = context.getResources();
            Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
            configuration.setLocale(locale);
            configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);

            resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

            return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        private static Context updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, String language) {
            Locale locale = new Locale(language);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);

            Resources resources = context.getResources();

            Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
            configuration.locale = locale;
            configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);

            resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

            return context;
        }
    }
   ```
2. Override `attachBaseContext` in your application class

   ```
    public class MyApplication<E> extends Application {

        protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
            super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(base, "en");
        }

    }
   ```
3. You need to override this `attachBaseContext` method in every activity, hence create a base class for all activities and override `attachBaseContext` in BaseActivity class

   ```
    public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
            Context context = LocaleHelper.onAttach(base, LocaleHelper.getLanguage(base));
            super.attachBaseContext(context);
            applyOverrideConfiguration(new Configuration(context.getResources().getConfiguration()));
        }

    }
   ```
4. Create your activities and extend the BaseActivity class. One or multiple activities can change language using the `changeApplicationLanguage` method. This method can be as per its application, i.e. onButtonClick, onDropDownSelection etc.

   ```
    public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private void changeApplicationLanguage(String localeCode) {
                LocaleHelper.setLocale(this, localeCode);
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        }

    }
   ```