# App Language resets to default when app is Killed

Tags: java, android, locale, setlocale

Hi I have an App which is a loads a webview and there's a [FLOWING DRAWER](https://github.com/mxn21/FlowingDrawer) in it.
I am trying to change the locale.
I have a `localeHelper` java class and an `AppClass` which `extends Application`

But its just not happening.

What happens is the locale changes only when I restart the app `super.Onbackpressed()`
but when I kills it ~ the locale turns back to english; it resets

I have been going mad from around 4 days.

Please help me, I'm a beginner;

`localeHelp.java`

```
public class LocaleHelper {

    private static final String SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "Locale.Helper.Selected.Language";

    public static Context onAttach(Context context) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
        return setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static Context onAttach(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, defaultLanguage);
        return setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static String getLanguage(Context context) {
        return getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    }

    public static Context setLocale(Context context, String language) {
        persist(context, language);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return updateResources(context, language);
        }

        return updateResourcesLegacy(context, language);
    }

    private static String getPersistedData(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, defaultLanguage);
    }

    private static void persist(Context context, String language) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        editor.putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, language);
        editor.apply();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        configuration.setLocale(locale);
        configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);

        return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static Context updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Resources resources = context.getResources();

        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        configuration.locale = locale;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);
        }

        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

        return context;
    }
}
```

simply calling
setLocale("fr");
with this function in MainActivity

```
 private void setLocale() {
        Locale locale;
        locale = new Locale("hi");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;


        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
       Intent intent = getIntent();
       finish();

       startActivity(intent);}
```

Comment: Are you storing your previously selected locale in Shared Preferences or in some other local storage? You will have to set the previously selected locale or English as default if none was previously selected when the app starts.

Comment: Thanks for replying.. I didn't understand about the default thing..
How can I set it as default?

Comment: So, by default language I mean, if you have not switched language in the app then Shared Preferences will not have any value so set English or your preferred language as default or initial language for Locale.

Comment: Please have a look at my code, the language is saved in SavedPrefrences well.

Comment: Also, are you using updated context from Locale for retrieving the string resources? I think if you're not doing it, this can resolve the issue.

Comment: Yes.. But what I mean is above code is working very well in another app.. But when I implemented it in my App it only works after I restart the app. But when I kill the app it resets.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243363/discussion-between-nikhil-jain-and-shane).

Comment: I got the above code from [Here](https://github.com/anurajr1/Multi-language_App) at Github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem: activity was recreated but the language was still the same..
Okay so after much trial and error this is what I got to work..

I put this code in OnResume

```
// todo load locale
        Locale current = getResources().getConfiguration().locale; 
 // todo get the current locale

        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+current, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String currentLanginString = current.toString(); // convert current language to string
        if(!currentLanginString.contains(wholeAppLanguage)) {
            recreate();
           // Toast.makeText(this, "recreatingResume", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        loadLocale();
```

and then I created the Loadlocale function

```
 public void loadLocale (){


        int langcode=0;
        String a="a";
        if (wholeAppLanguage.contains("hi")) {
            langcode = 0;
            a="hi";
        }
        else if (wholeAppLanguage.contains("en"))
        {
            langcode=1;
            a="en";
        }

        setLocale2(langcode);


    }
```

then it worked perfectly~

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the same problem of language getting reset after app kill, However, [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77787295/14399624) worked for me.

Summary:

- Override `attachBaseContext` method in all activities and application class.
- Save/Load the language preference to/from SharedPreferences.