# How to change Locale? Not working on some Devices

Tags: android, locale, multilingual

I'm writing app that support two language and I'm changing language with Change app Locale here my code :

```
 Locale locale = new Locale("fa");
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration configs = new Configuration();
            configs.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configs, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

And

in manifest I'm set `android:supportsRtl="true"`

These codes working in many Devices but in some devices not working . for example Texts not Translating but Direction change .

Tested Devices :

- Samsung J5Pro 2018  (android = 7.1): Worked
- Pixel 2 API 26 : Worked
- Samsung J7 2017 (android = 7): Worked
- Nexus 5  (android = 6) : Not Worked
- Samsung Galaxy G531 (android < lollipop) : Not Worked

Comment: it should work on nexus 4 also may you forgot to call `recreate()`

Comment: I have an activity that shows in the first time for choosing Language ,after user choose one of the languages then app direct user to the MainActivity. so i don't need to `recreate()` @Basil Battikhi

Answer (score 16, accepted):

i have found my solution , my problem was i'm inserted `"fa"` in Locale and my String Values Directory name was `values-fa-rlIR`, so names are different so not worked ,i'm wondering why it's working on some devices!

I'm just change the String Values Directory name from `values-fa-rlIR` to `values-fa` and it's working well.

Comment: Yes. After changing values-fa-rlIR to values-fa, its working. Cheers!

Comment: you saved my lot of time. bro .Thanks

Comment: can you Please explain whole process its mine values->strings->string.xml(default) and mine string.xml(bn) where should i change. please help if possible

Answer (score 3):

had the same problem.
Android Studio names the language folder like values-xx-rXX. Android 6.0 and lower can't handle this so You have to rename the foldername (I did it directly in Windows Explorer) to values-de.
Now it works for me on all devices

Answer (score 2):

or try this method , i used in many apps and it works

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    fun fixUpLocale(ctx: Context, newLocale: Locale) {
        val res = ctx.resources
        val config = res.configuration
        val curLocale = getLocale(config)
        if (curLocale != newLocale) {
            Locale.setDefault(newLocale)
            val conf = Configuration(config)
            conf.setLocale(newLocale)
            res.updateConfiguration(conf, res.displayMetrics);
        }
    }

    fun getLocale(config: Configuration): Locale {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return config.locales[0]
        } else {
            //noinspection deprecation
            return config.locale;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fun changeLang(context: Context, lang_code: String): ContextWrapper {
    defaultLanguage = lang_code
    var context = context
    val sysLocale: Locale

    val rs = context.resources
    val config = rs.configuration

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        sysLocale = config.locales.get(0)
    } else {
        sysLocale = config.locale
    }
    if (lang_code != "" && !sysLocale.language.equals(lang_code)) {
        val locale = Locale(lang_code)
        Locale.setDefault(locale)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            config.setLocale(locale)
        } else {
            config.locale = locale
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            context = context.createConfigurationContext(config)
        } else {
            context.resources.updateConfiguration(config, context.resources.displayMetrics)
        }
    }

    return ContextWrapper(context)
}
```

put this in every activity that you want to change the language

```
   override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
    val lang_code = Shared.defaultLanguage //load it from SharedPref
    val context = Shared.changeLang(newBase, lang_code)
    super.attachBaseContext(context)
}
```

you can try this code , it's in Kotlin  , and for more information you can check [Android N change language programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39705739/android-n-change-language-programmatically)

i think that it's an API matter.

Comment: i have problem in android Marshmallow and prelollipop but your code is for Android N so cant help me .

Comment: try this line  context.createConfigurationContext(config)

Comment: where should i use this ? this is not updating the Configuration. @B.mansouri

Comment: add the on attachBaseContext in every activity

Comment: i'm getting  android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference Error when write it in attacbaseContext in main activity and i'm in java no Kotlin

Comment: try to use a fixed local and try to test it , if it works , then try to use the local from the shared preferences

Comment: i'm use this , is it right ?@B.mansouri



 `@Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {

        Locale locale = new Locale("fa");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration configs = new Configuration();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            configs.setLocale(locale);
        } else {
            configs.locale = locale;
        }
        newBase.createConfigurationContext(configs);
        super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
    }`

Comment: try to make the langauge change in a function taht return context Wrapper and try again