# how to create multi language app in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm developing a multi language app and I'm using code below and it was working well but now it has problem in android api 24 and below without any error.
it just translate strings but I need my app be rtl.
what should I use instead of my code?

```
fun setNewLocale(mContext: Context, language: String): Context {
      setLanguagePref(mContext, language)
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) { 
           return updateResources(mContext, getLanguagePref(mContext)!!)             
      }
      return updateResourcesLegacy(mContext, getLanguagePref(mContext)!!)
}   

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)   
private fun updateResources(context: Context, language: String): Context {
        val locale = Locale(language)
        Locale.setDefault(locale)
        val configuration = context.resources.configuration
        configuration.setLocale(locale)

        return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration)
}

private fun updateResourcesLegacy(context: Context, language: String): Context {
       val locale = Locale(language)
       Locale.setDefault(locale)
       val resources = context.resources
       val configuration = resources.configuration
       configuration.locale = locale

       resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.displayMetrics)

       return context
 }
```

Comment: Add _android:supportsRtl="true"_ in manifest file within `<application>` tag.

Comment: i had been done it before, this code is working correctly in android api 25 and upper . @Piyush

Comment: Have you done [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38997356/change-language-programmatically-android-n-7-0-api-24)?

Comment: api 24 and below @Piyush

Comment: have you checked the link? You need to go with that way

Comment: which link? @Piyush

Comment: Above in comment i added

Comment: that answer gave by me.

Comment: yes thank you, i wanted to mention the answer here @Piyush

Comment: Had it been done?

Comment: @Piyush no i have problem with it yet

Comment: What problem ? Tell me

Answer (score 0):

For supporting multi language, if your users choose a language that uses right-to-left (RTL) scripts, such as Persian or Arabic, in the first you must support RTL in your app with lower API.
You can check official documents [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages) and for your case, [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages#SupportLayoutMirroring) section provide more details.

BTW you can check [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/rtl-support-on-android-here-is-all-you-need-know-e13f2df512e2) and [this ones](https://www.blueappsoftware.com/android-rtl-support-multi-language-app/) examples which provide some details and all you need to know.
Happy coding! movafagh bashi :)